# building project using gant and eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, gant

I am looking for a solution to build java project using `gant` inside `eclipse`, i searched web but didn't find any thing. May because I am not searching in the right direction because I have no idea about gant.

Actually I got all the java source and build.gant script from another developer, I made some minor changes in the java source only and since then looking for a way to build the solution without any luck.

I also tried to build solution using command line, downloaded binaries from ant and gant websites but for some reasons it's unable to find `ANT_HOME` variable, which I have already added as an environment variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gant is a tool for scripting Ant tasks using Groovy instead of XML to specify the logic.
Download GANT from the Codehaus website and build using it.
http://gant.codehaus.org/